# Future builder error, snapshot data empty

Tags: flutter, api, dart

Future builder is not working snapshot data is empty. I want build my catalog with gridview.builder, i think problem might be with my Product class.
And one more question, how to access objects inside the media class in json.
When i print my snapshot.data i got this:
flutter: null
this is my code:

```
late Future<List<Product>> productFuture = getProducts();

  static Future<List<Product>> getProducts() async {
    var url = '${Constants.API_URL_DOMAIN}action=catalog&category_id=$id';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    print(url);
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return body['data'].map<Product>(Product.fromJson).toList();
  }
```

this is my Product class:

```
class Product {
  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.categoryName,
    required this.media,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final String name;
  late final String categoryName;
  late final List<Media> media;

  Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    categoryName = json['category_name'];
    media = List.from(json['media']).map((e)=>Media.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['name'] = name;
    _data['category_name'] = categoryName;
    _data['media'] = media.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Media {
  Media({
    required this.id,
    required this.productId,
    required this.type,
    required this.links,
    required this.position,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final int productId;
  late final String type;
  late final Links links;
  late final String position;
  late final String createdAt;
  late final String updatedAt;

  Media.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    productId = json['product_id'];
    type = json['type'];
    links = Links.fromJson(json['links']);
    position = json['position'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['product_id'] = productId;
    _data['type'] = type;
    _data['links'] = links.toJson();
    _data['position'] = position;
    _data['created_at'] = createdAt;
    _data['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Links {
  Links({
    required this.s3,
    required this.cdn,
    required this.local,
  });
  late final String s3;
  late final String cdn;
  late final Local local;

  Links.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    s3 = json['s3'];
    cdn = json['cdn'];
    local = Local.fromJson(json['local']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['s3'] = s3;
    _data['cdn'] = cdn;
    _data['local'] = local.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Local {
  Local({
    required this.full,
    required this.thumbnails,
  });
  late final String full;
  late final Thumbnails thumbnails;

  Local.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    full = json['full'];
    thumbnails = Thumbnails.fromJson(json['thumbnails']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['full'] = full;
    _data['thumbnails'] = thumbnails.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Thumbnails {
  Thumbnails({
  required this.s150,
  required this.s350,
  required this.s750,
});
late final String s150;
late final String s350;
late final String s750;

Thumbnails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
s150 = json['150'];
s350 = json['350'];
s750 = json['750'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
  _data['150'] = s150;
  _data['350'] = s350;
  _data['750'] = s750;
  return _data;
}
}
```

My FutureBuilder

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
  future: productFuture,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final catalog = snapshot.data;
      return buildCatalog(catalog!);
    } else {
      print(snapshot.data);
      return Text("No widget to build");
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: do you get data bu printing `response`?

Comment: I got ```flutter: Instance of 'Response'```

Comment: Show your `FutureBuilder`. Of course the data is still null while it's loading. I don't know if that's the case here

Comment: try `print(response.statusCode);` and `response.body`

Comment: My FutureBuilder: 
`FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
              future: productFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final catalog = snapshot.data;
                  return buildCatalog(catalog!);
                } else {
                  print(snapshot.data);
                  return Text("No widget to build");
                }
              })`

Comment: when i print my `respone.body` i got correct data

Comment: Can you include `} else if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final catalog = snapshot.data;
        if (catalog == null) return Text("Got null on catalog");
        return buildCatalog(catalog);`